# WP8 updated to Googles API to v3 reference assemblie error

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, youtube-api

Hi I have updated my project references to include the latest Goolges.apis.Youtube.v3 library which I downloaded from NuGet using the console manager in Visual Studio 2013. Now when I compile the project I get the following error:

```
 Error   1   Cannot resolve reference assemblies. Please check the reference assemblies. Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.9.0.23042, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.
```

I have tried right clicking references > manage nuget packages and removing Goolges.apis.Youtube.v3 which also removes some dependencies etc.

I have done a clean bulild between uni-stalls and aslo deleted the following items from the packages.config file in the project directory:

```
    <package id="Google.Apis" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="wp80" />
    <package id="Google.Apis.Auth" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="wp80" />
    <package id="Google.Apis.Core" version="1.9.0" targetFramework="wp80" />
    <package id="Google.Apis.YouTube.v3" version="1.9.0.1280" targetFramework="wp80" />
```

As they still resided there after the unisatll..?

Any help with is much appreciated?

Thanks